# converting nested for loop to foreach

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to convert a nested for loop to foreach so that I can use parallel processing. This loop extracts information from the netCDF files based on a list of vectors that designate the position of the elements within the netCDF to extract. Here is my example:

load the necessary packages

```
# devtools::install_github("BigelowLab/fvcom", force = T)

library(fvcom)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
```

I have the netCDF files saved to a hard drive but they are available here: https://www.glerl.noaa.gov/data/chrp/Rowe_etal_2019_data/20170530-2/
For this example, I used the first 3 files on this page.

```
setwd("D:/FADR81 netCDF files/example for parallel processing")

file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.nc")
```

Create a list of vectors indicating the position of the elements I want to extract from each netCDF file. These are arbitrarily assigned here but in reality align with observations from another data set.

```
k1 <- 1:10
k2 <- c(1:5, 12:20, 45:51)
k3 <- 200:213

keep <- list(k1, k2, k3)
```

Run the loop to extract times and create rasters of temperature and dissolved oxygen.

```
system.time({

  times.all <- character(length(keep[[1]]))
  temp.all <- list()
  do.all <- list ()

  for(i in 1:length(keep)) {
    nc <- nc_open(file_list[[i]])
    mesh <- get_mesh_geometry(nc, what = 'lonlat')
    times <- character(length = length(keep[[i]]))
    temp <- list()
    do <- list()

    for(j in 1:length(keep[[i]])) {
      times[j] <- as.character(as.POSIXct(ncvar_get(nc, "Times", start=c(1, keep[[i]][j]), count=c(-1, 1)),
                                      format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))
  
      temp[[j]] <- get_mesh(nc, vars = "temp", mesh = mesh, time = keep[[i]][j], y = 20)
      temp[[j]] <- raster::stack(sapply('temp', function(f) fvcom::rasterize(temp[[j]], field = f), simplify = FALSE))
  
      do[[j]] <- get_mesh(nc, vars = "Dissolved_oxygen", mesh = mesh, time = keep[[i]][j], y = 20)
      do[[j]] <- raster::stack(sapply('Dissolved_oxygen', function(f) fvcom::rasterize(do[[j]], field = f), simplify = FALSE))
  
    }

    nc_close(nc)

    times.all <- c(times.all, times)
    temp.all <- c(temp.all, temp)
    do.all <- c(do.all, do)

  }

  times.all2 <- times.all[-which(times.all == '')]

})
```

I need to loop over hundreds of netCDF files and extract different elements from each file. I'm hoping that I can use foreach to parallelize this loop and improve the processing speed but I haven't had much luck figuring out how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe look into the lapply function for quicker looping

Comment: You need to understand `lapply` if you want to use `foreach`. `foreach` loops are much more similar to `lapply` loops than to `for` loops. Have you studied the [`foreach` package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html)?

Comment: @RAB `lapply` is generally not faster than a well-written `for` loop. Due to JIT byte-code compilation it could even be slower.

Comment: it seems to me that the first thing is to simplify the workflow ---- that is probably where you could save most time. But you do not provide a reproducible example and that makes it hard to help.

Comment: I have looked into the foreach vignette and other materials but maybe I need to back up a bit further and try to figure this out using lapply first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Roland's suggestion, I looked at the apply functions more closely and was able to rewrite my for loop as a function and use mapply() to duplicate my previous results. From there, it was an easy transition to mcmapply() in the parallel package. Here is my function and the code I used to run this using mcmapply() using file_list and keep from the original question.

```
get_dat <- function(x, z){
  nc <- nc_open(x)
  times <- as.character(as.POSIXct(ncvar_get(nc, "Times"), format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))
  times2 <- times[z]

  mesh <- get_mesh_geometry(nc, what = 'lonlat')
  temp <- list()
  do <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(z)) {

    temp[[i]] <- get_mesh(nc, vars = "temp", mesh = mesh, time = z[[i]], y = 20)
    temp[[i]] <- raster::stack(sapply('temp', function(f) fvcom::rasterize(temp[[i]], field = f), simplify = FALSE))

    do[[i]] <- get_mesh(nc, vars = "Dissolved_oxygen", mesh = mesh, time = z[[i]], y = 20)
    do[[i]] <- raster::stack(sapply('Dissolved_oxygen', function(f) fvcom::rasterize(do[[i]], field = f), simplify = FALSE))

  }


  nc_close(nc)

  exp.dat <- list(times2, temp, do)

  return(exp.dat)
}



system.time({

  new.dat <- mcmapply(get_dat, file_list, keep, mc.cores = 3)

  new.time <- list()
  new.temp <- list()
  new.do <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
    new.time[[i]] <- new.dat[1, i]
    new.temp[[i]] <- new.dat[2, i]
    new.do[[i]] <- new.dat[3, i]

  }

  new.time2 <- unlist(new.time, use.names = F)
  new.temp2 <- unlist(new.temp, use.names = F)
  new.do2 <- unlist(new.do, use.names = F)

})
```

You can reproduce this example by downloading the netCDF files from the link provided in the original question.